# Need assistance with pulling a row based on a condition of a date field being null or not

Tags: date, case

I'm working on a project where I need to pull a row based on a condition of dates. If the date is null AND order is 1 then pull it. If all dates in the column for the person are null then pull the most recently ended row.

In the example below, I need to figure out how to pull people based on the EndDate column. If EndDate is null for the person, then pull that row, IF all the rows on a person for EndDate is not null then pull the row with the most recent EndDate.

I'm stuck on how to implement that conditional. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Example:
Select bt.ID, bt.BillOrder, bt.Description, bt.EndDate
from BillTable bt
join *some other tables, not important*
where BillOrder = 1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question has been resolved.